# Using Adblock Plus filters to block HTML elements

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I was looking at this guide on how to block elements using ABP: https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide

As an example, I went to the options and added a filter for

```
blankmediagames.com/TownOfSalem/###fb-root
```

This should theoretically block the div with id `fb-root` containing a couple of iframes that use a lot of memory but are not needed, and the rule should only apply to the website `https://blankmediagames.com/TownOfSalem/` (the website for the Town of Salem game).

Though I have created the rule, I do not see the element being blocked. It is still there when I open the developer tools in Chrome, and I can also still see the subframe and its memory usage in Chrome's task manager (shown as `Subframe: https://facebook.com/` and using ~65K).

I must be doing something wrong. I would like to find a way to avoid having to manually end the subframe process each time I go here. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element hiding filters can only be restricted to domains, not to particular URLs on a domain. Here's a filter that should hide the element on that page:

```
blankmediagames.com###fb-root
```

If, however, you want to block the entire frame, an element hiding filter won't help. For that you need to create a blocking filter such as:

```
||facebook.com^$subdocument,domain=blankmediagames.com
```

That filter blocks any subframes on blankmediagames.com that contain content from facebook.com.

Alternatively, you could enable the "Block social media icons tracking" option in the Adblock Plus settings page (or a similar option in other ad blockers) which should block all social media elements.

Comment: I already had "Block social media icons tracking" enabled. The filters do work, though. Thanks.